# Как исправить неправильное отображение utf-8 только в одном месте на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, кодировка, dle

Поставил новый шаблон для dle 11.3 (utf-8), в настройках сайта(dle 11.3) тоже выставлено utf-8, все отображается корректно, кроме текста в новом дополнительном меню добавления новостей в админке

Выкладываю кусок исходного кода страницы

```
</script>
    <div class="editor-panel"><textarea id="short_story" name="short_story" class="wysiwygeditor" style="width:98%;height:300px;"></textarea></div>                           </div>
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group editor-group">
                              <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Полное описание:</label>
                              <div class="col-lg-10"><div class="editor-panel"><textarea id="full_story" name="full_story" class="wysiwygeditor" style="width:98%;height:300px;"></textarea></div>                            </div>
                            </div>
<div id="xfield_holder_poster" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">������ �� ������: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[poster]" id="xf_poster" value="" rel="essential" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_original" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">������������ ��������: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[original]" id="xf_original" value="" rel="essential" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_year" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">���: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[year]" id="xf_year" value="" rel="essential" data-rel="links" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_country" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">������: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[country]" id="xf_country" value="" rel="essential" data-rel="links" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_genre" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">����: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[genre]" id="xf_genre" value="" rel="essential" data-rel="links" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_director" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">�������� : <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[director]" id="xf_director" value="" rel="essential" data-rel="links" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_producer" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">�������� : <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[producer]" id="xf_producer" value="" rel="essential" data-rel="links" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_role" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">� �����: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[role]" id="xf_role" value="" rel="essential" data-rel="links" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_quality" class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">��������:</label>
  <div class="col-md-10"><select class="uniform" style="min-width:140px;" name="xfield[quality]"><option value="0">HDRip</option>
<option value="1">BDRip</option>
<option value="2">DVDRip</option>
<option value="3">CAMRip</option>
<option value="4">TS</option>
</select> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_video" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">URL �����: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[video]" id="xf_video" value="" rel="essential" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_bg_films" class="form-group" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">��� ������: </label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[bg_films]" id="xf_bg_films" value="" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_image-1" class="form-group" uid="essential" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">���� �� ������ (���� �� ���� �����������): <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[image-1]" id="xf_image-1" value="" rel="essential" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_image-2" class="form-group" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">���� �� ������: </label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[image-2]" id="xf_image-2" value="" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_image-3" class="form-group" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">���� �� ������: </label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[image-3]" id="xf_image-3" value="" /> 
  </div>
</div><div id="xfield_holder_image-4" class="form-group" >
  <label class="control-label col-md-2">���� �� ������: </label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
     <input type="text" style="width:99%;max-width:437px;" name="xfield[image-4]" id="xf_image-4" value="" /> 
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    onCategoryChange($('#category'));
// -->
</script>
```

На сайте текст отображается так же
Просмотрел все tpl файлы шаблона, не нашел этот блок
js скрипт тоже не нашел в исходных файлах шаблона

Как можно исправить этот косяк и где расположен этот блок?

Comment: открой его в блокноте и сохрани заново с кодировкой utf-8

Comment: Попробую, но проблема в том что этот блок отсутствует в исходниках шаблона и движка( не могу найти) все что до этого блока нашел и все что после него, а сам блок увы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в корне сайта (где index лежит) найти или создать файл с пустым именем и расширением .htaccess и там прописать следующее:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Если не поможет - можно попробовать написать это:

```
<IfModule mod_charset.c>
CharsetDisable on
</IfModule>
```

Сегодня сама столкнулась - при отображении информации из базы данных путается кодировка, исправляется в строчке на php, где к БД подключение идет, добавляется параметр. Как именно писать надо зависит от того, каким образом идет подключение к БД (их три, mysql_connect, mysqli и PDO)

Comment: c .htaccess пробовал, не помогло, "вылечил" полным удалением всего сайта и перезаливкой